# How can I create a stroked path with the Pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, pen-tool

I'm trying to make 3 px stroke with the regular pen tool without resorting to brush, pencil or anything like that. Is there any way to do that like in Illustrator?

This is the image where I'm stuck at:

[image: Don't think graphic design flow is for blind people]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, once you select your pen tool in Photoshop, select Make "Shape" from the pen tool options. This will allow you to add strokes with a bunch of different options.

[image]